# Stepper motor ROB-09238 & RPi2 what driver do I need, really need one?

Tags: driver

I am a bit noob with all kind of stuff. I have seen that the ROB-09238 is 'famous' and I want to manage it with the RPi2.

Technically do I really need that, two L9110H can make the work?

and what about this http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/motor-control/motor-drivers/h-bridge-driver-sn754410 is cheaper, can be used?

And in case do I need a driver any cheap that works with this stepper?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need something capable of sourcing the power, which the gpios can't as they are rated for 3V3 at a few milliamps.

Personally I'd use a [ULN2003A](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/electronic-components/misc-ic/uln2003a-darlington-array) or similar.  It should be able to supply the power the stepper needs.  You can drive the inputs from the Pi's gpios.

If you look at some driver boards you'll see they used miniature versions of the ULN2003A.

I've used the full-sized chip to drive bipolar steppers.

[image]